# @Refreshscope, how i can refresh value in realtime work?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

The task is to reread the config in real time. I found the article and after the original video to it, which told you how to do it, namely add an annotation @ RefreshScope and add some nightly to spring.yml props.
However, after adding all the necessary annotations and settings, I send a request curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {} http ://ip: port/actuator/refresh, to which the answer comes, what and where has changed in the form [app.profiles.config.port] for example.
But the parameters are not updated at the next request, I need help...

**DATA Class**

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "merchant-connection")
@RefreshScope
data class ConnectionsProfileProperties(
    val connectionProfiles: Map<String, ConnectionProperties>
) {
    data class ConnectionProperties(
        val smser: SmserProperties,
        val two: TwoProperties
    ) {
        data class SmserProperties(
            val host: String,
            val port: Int,
            val version: Int,
            val priority: Int,
            val dstHost: Int,
            val srcHost: Int,
            val phoneSrc: String,
            val socketTimeout: Duration
        )

        data class TwoProperties(
            val host: String,
            val port: Int,
            val useProxy: Boolean,
            val proxyHost: String?,
            val proxyPort: Int,
            val clerk: String,
            val password: String,
            val product: String,
            val retAddress: String,
            val version: String,
            val needDict: Int,
            val allVendors: Int,
            val avoidSession: Int,
            val readTimeout: Duration,
            val connectionTimeout: Duration
        )
    }
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
endpoints:
  actuator:
    enabled: true
```

By sending the request curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {} http ://ip: port/actuator/refresh, I receive such a response.

```
["merchant-connection.connection-profiles.profilename.smser.host"]
```

Comment: It states it changes but you state it doesn't. How and where do you use this?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have Api and configuration files located on the remote server

Comment: That doesn't answer my question (or at least my intended question). In your question you state you see that the property changed but that it isn't used. That is a bit contradicting and thus I was interested in how you check this.

Comment: @M.Deinum I consider so because it was so written in "guide" by means of which with introduced this code. It was claimed that if the value which was changed in a config is restored, it is the proof, at least so spoke.

Comment: So you assumed things, instead of seeing it yourself? The config is refreshed but you state it isn't reflected, but how? You still haven't really answered my question...

Comment: @M.Deinum I guess it is. I can argue that the changes in the config after the request did not latch on. And I don't know how I can make sure that they were actually sent, I draw all the conclusions based on what I saw in similar implementations.
Your question is where and how I use it. On the server in the folder there is an application build, in the same place in the next folder there are all configs that my site accesses. If I did not answer your question again, could you clarify or change the wording of your question?